# When I write this removes all the data from the svg file

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem with code that modifies an SVG file in Python 2.7. Simply speaking, it colors a box in a different table according to the id entered. But when I run it, it makes me an empty file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

    svg = (open('Draw.svg').read())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, 'lxml')

    tags = soup.find_all('path')

    for path in tags:
        if path.attrs['id']==('FFF'):
            print(path.attrs['style'])
            Str = re.sub( r'fill:#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}',
                     r'fill:#ffffff',
                     path.attrs['style'])
            path.attrs['style'] = Str
            print(Str)

            print(path.attrs['style'])

    svg = open('Draw.svg', 'w')
    #svg.write(tags)
    svg.close()
```

Did I miss something? Any help would be appreciated.

I'm also thinking of improving the code to have multiple inputs to color more boxes at once.

I changed a bit of the code and it always returns an empty file but with an error when I try to open it :

Error domain 1 code 4 on line 1 column 1

```
with open('Draw.svg', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(tags))
```

When I get this error, my code is well executed, I checked it by opening the file for the xml code of the svg but it fucked up the mess the xml code, I have the impression that it missing parts of codes compared to the original image

Comment: The shown code doesn't write anything to the file as the "write" is commented out.

Comment: It also doesn't work if it's commented on because I did a different test. It's basically uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
# svg = utils.getFileContent('Draw.svg')
svg = '''
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path id="FFF" style="fill:#aabbcc" />
</svg>
''' # Your svg content
doc = SimplifiedDoc(svg)

tags = doc.selects('path#FFF')

for path in tags:
    print(path['style'])
    Str = doc.replaceReg(path['style'], 'fill:#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}', 'fill:#ffffff')
    path.setAttr('style', Str)
    print(Str)
    print(path['style'])

utils.saveFile('Draw.svg', doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path id="FFF" style="fill:#ffffff" />
</svg>
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm looking to do it with beautiful soup

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with beautiful soup. The example of using SimplifiedDoc here is for your reference only.